# Print the values of knapsack solution

Tags: c, recursion, knapsack-problem

I have the following solution for the knapsack problem:(wt[] is the weights array, val[] is the values array, n is the arrays size, index is the current item that we are trying (for the recursion) and arr is an array that represents weather or not item i was included in the solution.

```
int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n, int index, int arr[])
{
   if (n == index || W == 0)
       return 0;
   if (wt[index] > W)
       return knapSack(W, wt, val, n, index+1 );

   int with=val[index]+knapSack(W-wt[index], wt, val, n, index+1);
   int without=knapSack(W, wt, val, n, index+1);

   if(with>without){
       arr[index]=1;
       return with;
   }
   else{
       arr[index]=0;
       return without;
   }

}
```

I am trying to print, in this recursive solution the items that are chosen, by setting the indexes of the taken ones in an array (res) to 1.
As I understand, if `with>without`, it means that I am choosing the current item, or item #index. So why is this not returning a right value?
I am using the recursive algorithm for a reason, I know using the memoization version can be easier here. 
Example:
Weights: 5 6 7 10 11
Values: 2 4 5 6 9
W=25
Will return 5 ones in array res. When solution is 18 with items 2,3,5 (starting from index 1).

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: What did you see when you stepped through it in the debugger?

Comment: What do all the function parameters represent?

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Premise 1**: in your code, the recursion calls to `knapSack` are not passing `arr`, which should cause a compilation error, I assume it's just a copy/paste error.

**Premise 2**: with the data you proposed, the resulting `arr` value is not all `1` as you indicated, but `01011`, which is still incorrect.

Consider the hypothetical situation in which, during the execution of your function, `with` is greater than `without`: during the `with` calculation `arr` is filled with the correct values; but then start the `without` calculation which is going to overwrite the `arr` values.

Since `with` is greater than `without`, the returned `arr` will be the wrong one, and this is the cause of the problem.

A simple fix would be to make a copy of the `arr` returned by the `with` calculation so it is not going to be overwritten by the `without` calculation, for example:

```
int with=val[index]+knapSack(W-wt[index], wt, val, n, index+1, arr);

// copy the "with" arr
int arrWith[n];
copyArr(arr, arrWith, n);

int without=knapSack(W, wt, val, n, index+1, arr);

if(with>without){
    // restore the "with" arr
    copyArr(arrWith, arr, n);

    arr[index]=1;
    return with;
}
else{
    arr[index]=0;
    return without;
}
```

`copyArr` is simply:

```
void copyArr(int arr[], int arrDest[], int n) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arrDest[i] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

With this fix the resulting value of `arr` is correctly `01101`.